# Spring Kafka Listener receiving duplicate messages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

My Spring Kafka Listener is receiving duplicate  messages, i can see the messages are being polled from same partition and offset and the same timestamp. In my code, i keep track every incoming message and identify the duplicates, but in this case, i cannot even reject it from processing as both messages - original and duplicate are received at almost same time, and the first record is not even committed in the database tracking table.
1.Please suggest how i should avoid polling the duplicate messages, i dont understand why it is being polled twice- only under load.
2. How i can handle this in tracking table, if message 1 metadata is being processed and not committed in

```
the tracking table, message 2 comes and is not able to find that record in tracking table and proceeds with processing the duplicate message again.

config of the listener based on my use case:
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 50); 
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
```

Comment: What you are suggesting makes no sense to me, unless you  have somehow configured 2 instances of your listener. Create a stripped down version of your project that exhibits this behavior so we can see what you have done wrong.

Comment: Yes Gary, I have two consumers and two partitions which process messages from that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two consumers need to have the same `group.id` property so that the partitions are distributed across them.

If they are in different consumer groups, they will both get all the records.

Comment: Thanks, They have the same group.id. It works fine if there is no load, however, under load testing, it sometimes fetches a message that was already fetches, in other words, same messages is polled twice.

Comment: Can't happen; sorry - unless a rebalance occurs - in which case you need to reduce `max.poll.records` and/or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Gary - Is it possible to control commiting of the offset in the KafkaListener code, In case an exception occurs, i dont want the offset to move further.

Comment: Just throw an exception; with the `SeekToCurrrentErrorHandler` (which is now the default error handler), the failed record will be redelivered. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#error-handlers).